# Laravel Eloquent filter not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a filter in Laravel.
I want to filter on the database field `transmission` but it is not working.

Here is my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Occasion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hexon_occasions';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use EloquentBuilder;
use App\Occasion;

class OccasionController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $occasions = EloquentBuilder::to(
            Occasion::class,
            $request->all()
         );

        return $occasions->get();
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        $occasions = Occasion::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('occasions.show')->with('occasions', $occasions);
    }
}
```

The filter:

```
namespace App\EloquentFilters\Occasion;

use Fouladgar\EloquentBuilder\Support\Foundation\Contracts\Filter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class TransmissionFilter implements Filter
{
    /**
     * Apply the age condition to the query.
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param mixed   $value
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('transmission', $value);
    }
}
```

And the URL i am using is: https://www.laravel.bvdodev.nl/occasions?filter[transmission]=H

But I am getting the error: `Not found the filter: FilterFilter`

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Where is the Filter class located?

Comment: It is in /App/EloquentFilters/Occasion/TransmissionFilter.php

Comment: You are using `implements` instead of `extends` inside your filter, see [here](https://github.com/mohammad-fouladgar/eloquent-builder#define-a-filter)

Comment: @Remul; I did change it but still 'FilterFilter not found' error.

Comment: It seems you are using a package for filtering data, why don't you write it via a simple ```where``` query?

Comment: Did you rename this filter? maybe `composer dump-autoload` helps